# apache Как сделать так, чтобы папка была доступна только по алиасу?

Tags: apache

Как то так:

```
Alias /myapplet /usr/share/myapplet

<Directory /usr/share/myapplet>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Но эти директивы не работают :(

Comment: Если запрос содержит  `/usr/share/myapplet` возвращай 404 или 403. А алиас перенаправляй куда хочешь. Закрывать доступ к директории не надо, тогда и по алиасу не попадешь

Comment: Если ё/usr/share/myapplet` находится вне корневой директории веб сайта, то кроме как по алиасу в нее все равно не попадешь.  Так что нужно сделать `Order Allow,Deny` и `Allow from All`